# php sort array comparing value and push smaller values last

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a value and comparing that value i want to change order of an array

for eg. here 3 is value so i need array order to be

5,6,1,2

so values less then 3 shifts last in array.

```
<?php

$value=3;

$array=array(6,2,5,1);

asort($array);

print_r($array);

?>
```

Comment: What output you want?

Comment: output should be array(5,6,1,2)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look on the below code, it may help you. You need to use array_filter with call back function to make 2 arrays then u can merge them.

```
  $value=3;
  $array=array(6,2,5,1);
  asort($array);
  $right = array_filter($array, function($elem) use($value){
      return $elem < $value;
  });
  $left = array_filter($array, function($elem) use($value){
     return $elem > $value;
  });
  //print_r($right);
  //print_r($left);
  $res = array_merge($left,$right);
  print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$value=3;
$output = $array;

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if ($value >= $v) {
        unset($output[$k]);

        $output[] = $v;
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used loop, see if it helps you:

```
foreach ($array as $ele){
    if($ele < $value){
        $rightArr[] = $ele;
    }else{
        $output[] = $ele;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_merge($output,$rightArr));
```